# React Redux: What does this syntax mean

Tags: javascript, react-redux

I have implemented redux in a react app, but I am confused as to this syntax:

```
connect(mapState)(MyComponent)
```

Why does the second parameter need to be in separate braces if both are passed to connect?

Comment: `connect(mapState)` returns a function, which then accepts a component as an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are probably used to the syntax. Only you are seeing everything in one step
Think of it this way which is equivelent;

```
const enhancer = connect(mapState);
const YourConnectedComponent = enhancer(MyComponent);
```

So thats the same if you instead of allocating the result of connect in a variable you use it directly since its a function you would see it as:

```
const YourConnectedComponent = connect(mapState)(MyComponent)
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically your component will be connected with the `redux` store once:

1. `connect` has been called with the `mapStateToProps` variable which returns a function
2. after this function will be called with the passed `MyComponent` parameter.

From the `redux` [documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#overview):

> The connect() function connects a React component to a Redux store. It provides its connected component with the pieces of the data it needs from the store, and the functions it can use to dispatch actions to the store.

This way `redux` will handle the `props` state changes in your component automatically.